# Как формировать ключи доступа к боту на определенное время?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, бот, python-telegram-bot

**Доброго времени суток!** Написан хороший, полезный Telegram бот на python, хочется сделать его приватным - человек пишет мне, я создаю ключ доступа на определенное время (пример ключа: *PJZ3SbvkK1bM* - 1 день), пользователь вводит ключ в бота и получает доступ на указанное время (1 день). По истечении указанного времени доступа у пользователя больше не будет, и он сможет написать мне за новым ключом.

---

### Мои наброски:

**Создание файла с ключами:**

```
keys = open("Keys.txt", "w+")
```

**Создание нового ключа:**

```
if message.text == 'Добавить ключ' and message.from_user.id == admin_id:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите ключ')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, save_new_key)
```

**Запись ключа:**

```
def save_new_key(message):
    if message.text == 'Отменить':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Отменено.')
    else:
        keys = open("Keys.txt", "a+")
        keys.write('\n'message.text)
        keys.close()
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ключ добавлен')
    adminpanel(message)
```

**Авторизация пользователя:**

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    if access(str(message.from_user.id)) == True:
        main_btn(message)
    else:
        get_access(message)

def access(user_id):
    if f'{user_id}.txt' in os.listdir('Members/WithKey'):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def get_access(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введи ключ доступа')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, check_key)

def check_key(message):
    with open("Keys.txt") as f:
       keys = f.read()
    keys_list = eval(keys)

    for onekey in keys_list:
        if message.text == onekey:
            num = int(message.text)
            try:
                file = os.listdir('Members/All/')[num - 1]
                with open(f'Members/All/{file}', 'r') as f:
                    g = f.read()
                    with open(f'Members/WithKey/{file}', 'w') as d:
                        d.write(g)
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Доступ к боту получен!')
                main_btn(message)
            except:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Произошла ошибка')
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Неверный ключ')
```

---

### Вопрос.

Что-то мне подсказывает, что этот код не сработает сразу как надо, я еще не совсем мастер. Можно сказать новичок. Подскажите пожалуйста, как же все таки выдавать доступ на определенное время, а не на всегда?
Я был бы вам очень благодарен, если бы получил ответ вместе с кусками кода. Спасибо!

---

**UPD:** Возможно, лучше создавать группы пользователей следующим образом:

```
if os.path.exists('Members/All'):
    pass
else:
    os.mkdir('Members/All')
if os.path.exists('Members/WithKey'):
    pass
else:
    os.mkdir('Members/WithKey')
```

Comment: Самая большая проблема, что сейчас у вас проверка только на `start`, а это происходит только при первом подключении пользователя. Раз подключится - проверка пройдет и он дальше будет себе пользоваться ботом (старт то больше не вызывается) Нужно  делать проверку в каждом обработчике, и если ключ уже протух - просить ввести новый.

Comment: Я и планировал у каждого последующего ответа на сообщения дописывать проверку на наличие доступа

Answer (score 1):

Не нужно работать с файлами, работайте с базой.

1. Создайте таблицы `keys` и `keys_users`.
2. Поля в `keys`: `id`, `key`, `days`.
3. Поля в `keys_users`: `id`, `user_id`, `key_id`, `until_at`, `created_at`.
4. Добавьте ключи в базу (`keys`), и у каждого ключа укажите, сколько дней активен этот ключ.
5. Привязывайте ключи к пользователям (`keys_users`) указывая айди ключа и айди юзера (`key_id` и `user_id`). К это записи устанавливайте срок действия от текущей даты до +количество дней ключа.
6. Проверяйте где нужно, есть ли у пользователя активный ключ.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше предложение! Звучит хорошо, но только я сам никогда не работал с базами и не совсем понимаю как бот будет это проверять. И как присваивать ключи пользователям.